# How to upgrade react-router-dom to v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I Upgrade all Switch elements to Routes and components change to element
How to change what's left to v6

Routes.js

```
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from 'react';
import { HashRouter as Routes, Route, Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import Loading from './components/Loading';
import { ProtectedRoute, WithLayoutRoute } from './routers';
import { AdminLayout, PublicLayout } from './layouts';
const MovieList = lazy(() => import('./pages/Admin/MovieList'));
const MoviePage = lazy(() => import('./pages/Public/MoviePage'));

const Routess = () => {
  return (
    
    <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
      
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login/>} />
          <Route exact path="/register" element={<Register/>} />
          <WithLayoutRoute exact path="/movie/:id" layout={PublicLayout} layoutProps={{ withFooter: false }} element={<MoviePage/>} />
          <ProtectedRoute exact path="/admin/movies" layout={AdminLayout} element={<MovieList/>} />
          <Route path="*" element={() => '404 NOT FOUND'} />
          
        </Routes>
    </Suspense>
  );
};

export default Routess;
```

Ok, i upgraded my Routes.js as you said, but i dont update WithLayoutRoute and ProtectedRoute. How change it?
I don't know how to change it:
ProtectedRoute.js:

```
import...
const ProtectedRoute = ({ layout: Layout, component: Component, isAuthenticated, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      isAuthenticated ? (
        <Layout>
          <Component {...props} />
        </Layout>
      ) : (
        <Navigate to={{ pathname: '/', state: { from: props.location } }} />
      )
    }
  />
);

ProtectedRoute.propTypes = {
  isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool
};
ProtectedRoute.defaultProps = {
  isAuthenticated: false
};
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.authState.isAuthenticated
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ProtectedRoute);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you've provided what remains is fixing the custom route components. `react-router-dom@6` no longer supports custom route components and only `Route` and `React.Fragment` components are valid children of the `Routes` component. You *should* see invariant warnings/errors with the above code if you have actually run it.

Convert the custom route components to layout components that render and `Outlet` each for nested `Route` components to be rendered into.

Example:

```
const WithLayoutRoute = ({ layout: Layout, layoutProps}) => {
  ...
  return (
    <Layout {...layoutProps}>
      <Outlet />
    </Layout>
  );
};

const ProtectedRoute = ({ layout: Layout }) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  ...
  return (
    <Layout>
      {auth
         ? <Outlet />
         : <Navigate to="/login" replace state={{ from: location }} />
      }
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

Wrap the routes you in new layout routes.

```
const Routess = () => {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login/>} />
        <Route path="/register" element={<Register/>} />

        <Route
          element={(
            <WithLayoutRoute
              layout={PublicLayout}
              layoutProps={{ withFooter: false }}
            />
          )}
        >
          <Route path="/movie/:id" element={<MoviePage/>} />
        </Route>

        <Route element={<ProtectedRoute layout={AdminLayout} />}>
          <Route path="/admin/movies" element={<MovieList/>} />
        </Route>

        <Route path="*" element={'404 NOT FOUND'} />
      </Routes>
    </Suspense>
  );
};
```

See [Layout Routes](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#layout-routes) for more detail.

Comment: Thank you, i upgraded Routess.js as you said, but I could not change ProtectedRoute.js and WithLayoutRoute.